# Curve being tangent to a surface

Tags: calculus

Verify that the curve $\displaystyle x^{2}-y^{2}+z^{2}=1, xy+xz = 2$ is tangent to the surface $xyz-x^{2}-6y+6=0$ at the point (1, 1, 1).

---

I have found the gradient vector for the surface, which would be:

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=yz-2x=-1$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=xz-6=-5$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=xy=1$

However, I'm not sure on how to proceed on the other question (it is a curve, but they are giving us two different equations). How can i work around this problem? I have tried finding the gradient vector for the curve, but i'm not sure if it will work as it is a curve (and the gradient vectors results actually differ for both surfaces).

Answer (score 2):

You should prove that the tangent vector of the curve at $(1,1,1)$ is contained in the tangent plane of the surface, or is orthogonal to the normal vector to the surface at $(1,1,1)$ which is given by the gradient. You calculated the normal vector which is $(-1,-5,1)$.

Now you need to calculate the tangent vector to the curve in $(1,1,1)$. The curve is given by the intersection of two surfaces, so the tangent vector would be orthogonal to both normal vectors in $(1,1,1)$ of the two surfaces.

---

$(S_1):  x^2-y^2+z^2=1$ has normal vector $(2x,-2y,2z)$ which evaluated in your point gives $v_2=(2,-2,2)$.

$(S_2): xy+xz=2$ has normal vector $(y+z,x,x)$ which evaluated in your point gives $v_3=(2,1,1)$.

Solve now the system given by $v\cdot v_2=0$ and $v\cdot v_3=0$ to get $v_1-v_2+v_3=0$ and $2v_1+v_2+v_3=0$. Eliminate $v_1$ to get $3v_2-v_3=0$. So if $v_2=\alpha$ we have $v_3=3\alpha$ and $v_1=-2\alpha$. So $v=\alpha(-2,1,3)$.

The vector $v$ is the tangent vector to the curve at $(1,1,1)$, and it should be orthogonal to $(-1,-5,1)$. Indeed if we calculate the scalar product we get $(-2,1,3)(-1,-5,1)=2-5+3=0$.

Comment: I got something along the lines of what you did, but i want to check if my argument is as well correct. I supposed that x was a function of "t" (a parameter), as well as y and z. Then i differentiated both expressions with respect to "t" and i found that 2(dx/dt)-2(dy/dt)+2(dz/dt) = 0 and 2(dx/dt)+(dy/dt)+(dz/dt), by plugging in the values of x, y and z into the expressions which are 1, and i found that the solution to the system was given by x = a(-2/3 1/3 1), where a is a parameter. Then i assumed say, we have a = 1. Then the scalar product: (-2/3)(-1)+(1/3)(-5)+(1)(1) = 0. Is this correct?

Comment: It is basically the same thing. Note that you obtained the same equations.